# How to set up a C# model to convert properties to Knockout computed observables

Tags: c#, knockout.js, durandal

We're using durandal to convert C# models to Knockout viewmodels for rendering. I'm wondering if there's a way I can set up a C# model with properties that have a set method or something so that the bindings and dependencies are already present when I get the Knockout viewmodel.

I'd like a scenario like this to happen.

```
public class MyObject{
  public string FirstName{get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set}
  private string fullName{get; set;}
  public FullName{
    get{return fullName;}
    set{fullName = FirstName +" "+LastName}
  }
```

I've used the prime example Knockout uses when explaining computed observables. I understand how to achieve this in purely JS viewmodel. However, I'd like to set up my C# model similar to what I have above (I don't think this actually works) in order to get back a computed that already has it's dependencies.

I'm not entirely sure it's possible, but it sure would be nice.

Comment: Can you please add small example of what do you want to achieve as result?

Answer (score 2):

Max Brodin mentions KnockoutMVC which is a huge antipattern and you lose almost all benefits with Knockout since it creates server callbacks for almost everything you do.

A better option is to use for example [DuoCode](http://duoco.de/) or Open source alternative [WootzJs](https://github.com/kswoll/WootzJs)

These tools will compile C# code to Javascript, I have only tested DuoCode but it was farily easy to create a Knockout binding for it. After that its easy to create ViewModels like

```
using Knockout;

namespace ViewModels
{
    public class FooViewModel
    {
            private readonly Observable<string> bar;        
            private readonly Observable<string> computed;        

        public FooViewModel()
        {
            bar = Global.Observable("HelloWorld"); //Translates to ko.observable("HelloWorld") on client
            computed = Global.Computed(() => bar.Get() + "COMPUTED");
        }

        public Observable<string> Bar { get { return bar; } }
        public Observable<string> Computed { get { return computed; } }
    }
}
```

I have also created bindings for ko.mapping like

`Mapping.Map(new { bar = "DataFromserver" }, null, this);` which translates to 
`ko.mapping.fromJS({ bar = "DataFromserver" }, null, this);` on client

Answer (score 1):

The idea is good, but it's not going to work in the real world projects. Your C# code need to be translated to javascript and it could work for simple cases like yours. But if you change your computed property to more something complicated you will have problems.

There is a [knockoutmvc project](http://knockoutmvc.com/) that provides such functionality. They have [hello world](http://knockoutmvc.com/HelloWorld) sample which looks like something you can use as a start. You just need to mark your property with attributes

```
public class HelloWorldModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Computed]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }
}
```

And in razor view you should call:

```
@{
  var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

Comment: Look at this example, http://knockoutmvc.com/ClickCounter check the network tab in Chome console. Each click generates a server roundtrip

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want auto-translation of computed properties. That's a big ask for a small convenience. I think I could do it for trivial expressions, but how would you map .NET library methods like string.Format to javascript? You would need a client side library replicating the semantics. Big job, not worth the effort.